# How to check if date is in a uncommon format in python?

Tags: python, date, format

I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to see if a date from a .json is in the right format.
Now the format looks like "2020-03-10T11:30:09.782+00:00" as an example.
The last digits are supposed to be the time shift I guess.

Because of the "T" and the time shift I don't think I can work with datetime and re.match didn't work for me either.
Which approach should I follow to compare the format?

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  Do you want to _extract_ these values?  Convert them to datetime?  Something else?

Comment: This looks like [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Python should be able to parse this, e.g. with https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat or https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/  You'd need to define next what common and uncommon formats are in your application, and how you want to handle them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the goal is just to check if the .json submitted from a 3 party is correct and usable for further operations.